# reset count for `v`

Tags: visual-mode, count

According to `:help v` a count of `1` provided to `v` will select the same number of characters as the previous selection, but starting from the current cursor (see full help below). When there was no previous selection, it will select `count` characters. Is it possible to reset this count to obtain the default behaviour?

```
[count]v    Start Visual mode per character.
            With [count] select the same number of characters or
            lines as used for the last Visual operation, but at
            the current cursor position, multiplied by [count].
            When the previous Visual operation was on a block both
            the width and height of the block are multiplied by
            [count].
            When there was no previous Visual operation [count]
            characters are selected.  This is like moving the
            cursor right N * [count] characters.  One less when
            'selection' is not "exclusive".
```

Comment: By "default behavior" you mean if you have a previous selection of 5 char and use `2v` you want to select 2 chars instead of 2x5=10 chars?

Comment: That is exactly what I mean yes. I don't really see the use-case for quickly selecting 5x2 characters (or lines etc.), but I regularly find myself wanting to select a number of lines using e.g. `2V`.

Comment: I see I wasn't sure I understood correctly. I can't think of a better answer than Rich's one actually.

Answer (score 2):

One easy way to workaround this would be by typing:

```
v"_y
```

This will yank a single character into the black hole register. Therefore, it's only effect is to reset the visual count to 1.

Specifying the blackhole register with `"_` isn't strictly necessary, but it prevents the operation from affecting your registers.

Note that setting the visual count to 1 only has the desired effect if `'selection'` is not set to `exclusive`. (Its default value is `inclusive`.) If `'selection'` *is* set to `exclusive`, then your subsequent `[count]v` operation will still select `[count]` characters, which for `selection=exclusive` is one too few.